# Pygame, why does my rectangle not move

Tags: pygame

I don't get why the rectangle is not changing it's y position when i press the up key. I don't get any errors and everything is showing up.

import pygame
from pygame.locals import *

class SnekHead(object):

```
def __init__(self, screensize):

    self.screensize = screensize

    self.center_x = int(screensize[0]*0.5)
    self.center_y = int(screensize[1]*0.5)

    self.width = 50
    self.height = 50

    self.rect = pygame.Rect(self.center_x-25, self.center_y-50, self.width, self.height)

    self.color = (100, 255, 100)

    self.speed = 10

    self.direction = 0

def update(self):

    self.center_y +=  self.direction*self.speed



def render(self, screen):
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, self.color, self.rect, 0)
```

def run_game():
    pygame.init()

```
screensize = (640, 480)


background_image = pygame.image.load('Sky_back_layer.png')

screen = pygame.display.set_mode(screensize)

clock = pygame.time.Clock()

snake = SnekHead(screensize)

running = True

while running:

    clock.tick(64)

    for event in pygame.event.get():

        if event.type == KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == K_ESCAPE:
                running = False

            elif event.key == K_UP:
                snake.direction = -1

    snake.update()

    screen.blit(background_image, (0, 0))

    snake.render(screen)

    pygame.display.flip()

pygame.quit()
```

run_game()

Comment: Try reposting your code so it's easier to read. First post the code, then highlight it all, then press the code button. It will format better.

Answer (score 0):

Ask yourself this question. What is the value of `self.rect` after the key is pressed? (You decrement `snake.direction` when the key is pressed, then you update `snake.center_y`, but  `snake.rect` remains the same and so does the position of the rectangle because that is what you are passing to `pygame.draw.rect()` in your `render()` function)